# Why has all my text turned black when set it in my android theme to be white?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-theme

I am trying to make my textview textColor white in my AppTheme but it appears as black in my fragment.  The fragment has been set to have a background like so:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_settings"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
```

The page looks like this now:
[image: image of user settings fragment]

The theme looks like this:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
     <!--   <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item> -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/whiteText</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">#2d314d</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/whiteText</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:attr/colorBackground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyButton" parent="android:Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">#FF5A79</item>

        <item name="android:textColor">@color/whiteText</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

Also, not sure this is related but just in case, I was using the Theme Editor and it gives a warning - Not enough contrast with colorButtonNormal - by the android:textcolorPrimary.  I don't know much about what   colorButtonNormal is nor can I find any info about it.  This is what my theme editor looks like with my current settings:
[image]

While I'm at it another problem is the text color is white inside the editText fields (WEIGHT and AGE) which is where I need to change it to be black.

Thanks for any help, this android styling stuff is driving me nuts.

Comment: In the manifest, did you set the theme to the one you want for the particular activity?

Comment: In the manifest the theme for the activity is set to    
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", I think android studio  set that when the activity was created.  When I remove it or remove the NoActionBar part the app crashes when I install it on the emulator.

Comment: Try to use android:theme="@style/AppTheme" and see if it works.

Comment: Tried that, it crashes on launch or maybe even on install.

Comment: What's the thrown exception and what is your activity extending?

Comment: no exception is thrown, it just crashes.  The activity extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; , does the fragment have to extend something special too?

Answer (score 0):

Go for this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_settings"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

this will solve your problem. You are setting parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" that is why everything is black

Comment: But I override the text colors in my AppTheme, why don't they apply?

Comment: I just tried that and as expected it just turned the background color to white rather than the text color in the textviews.  The background color above is right.

Comment: You can do one thing define Style for TextViews with white color and you can use it that will solve your problem.

Comment: OK will try that but why weren't the colors in AppTheme doing the job?

Comment: it's default android sdk's style, we can't edit that style.

Comment: But I was inheriting from it, can't we set our derived theme however we want?

Comment: Thanks, I went with the custom textview style,   that works for now but it would be nice to understand why it wasn't working the other way.